# How to get Public IP Address from Window Phone 7 using STUN Protocol?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, networking

I knw there is alternative to that we can hit on website like findmyip to get the ip. But i have a requiremnet to use STUN protocol.

Comment: There is a good overview of [STUN on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), with links to specifications and code libraries in several languages. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: most of libraries i tried is not working on WP7....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a STUN-Client for C# which you can use as a starting point for implementing the same code for Windows Phone 7. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18492/STUN-Client

This Microsoft page describes creating UDP sockets in C# on Windows Phone 7: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202864%28v=vs.92%29.aspx